# Ubuntu 16.04: Maps mouse device of capacitive touch display to own screen

Tags: 16.04, unity, multiple-monitors, input-devices

I have a dual screen setup with a common HD monitor (HDMI) and a small 5" 800*480 display with capacitive touch in a dual screen setup, where the HD monitor is left of the 5" display.

The problem is, that the mouse input device of the cap touch is mapped all over the full screen, so that it is unusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it this way:

1. get device name of screen using xrandr
2. get device id of the mouse input device of the 5" screen
3. invoked xinput to map the input device to the 5" screen

the final call is:

```
$ sudo xinput map-to-output 14  HDMI2
```